# Wix - open a page with argument?

Tags: velo

I need to navigate to a new page, then call a specific function in that page.
In other words, open a page when a certain box is collasped/hidden etc.

Should I pass parameter from page1 to page 2 ? how ?
Can I call a function from page1 to page2 then navigate (using `wix.location` ) ?

Answer (score 1):

So you can use wix-location to pass a queryParam to the page you're going to and then just run a code in the other page that reads from the URL.

[Wix-location API](https://www.wix.com/code/reference/wix-location.html#to)

Hope this helps..